# What are benefits of deploying a Spring ApplicationContext as a J2EE RAR file?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I came accross a heading in spring documentation as "Deploying a Spring ApplicationContext as a J2EE RAR file" but i am not able to connect to this topic. I do not have any clue why would we do this and what are its benefits. Any practical example. If any one can help. If there are any design benefits achieved than what are those benefits. Also if anyone can give an example how to achieve it.

Comment: Are you surce it was RAR? Not EAR or WAR?

Comment: Please go to this link http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-create and search 3.13.5 Deploying a Spring ApplicationContext as a J2EE RAR file. You will find it.

Comment: Isn't the doc you referenced clear enough? That's basically if you want to deploy a _headless_ war to the JavaEE server, i.e. a component that does not serve any HTTP endpoints. That section also redirects you to [SpringContextResourceAdapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jca/context/SpringContextResourceAdapter.html) that explains how to configure it

Comment: What is headless war? These terms are some what new to me.